# Rust - как разбить строку по разделителю и взять только значение после 2 разделителя?

Tags: rust

Необходимо читать строку из файла (это понятно как), разбивать ее по разделителю и вывести только значения после 2 разделителя. Можно ли это реализовать через `split`?

```rust
let _contents = fs::read_to_string(fname).expect("Should have been able to read the file");
let parts = _contents.split(",");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не совсем очевидная постановка, но вот вам [варианты](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32152ef16dd4e8d423b0106fa30dd56f).

- Если нужен **третий** элемент-подстрока, то после разделения берем нужный элемент последовательности с помощью [nth](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth):

```rust
let input = "some,line,of,text,with,delimiters".to_string();

let third_element: &str = input.split(",").nth(2).expect("...");

println!("{third_element}"); // -> "of"
```

- Если нужны значения-подстроки **начиная с третьей** (без разделителей), то пропускаем первые две методом [skip](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip), остальные можем собрать, например, в вектор:

```rust
let input = "some,line,of,text,with,delimiters".to_string();

let rest_elements: Vec<&str> = input.split(",").skip(2).collect();

for element in rest_elements {
    print!("{element}");  // -> "oftextwithdelimiters"
}
```

- Если нужна **подстрока из остатка текста** после второго разделителя (включая остальные разделители), то делим входную строку на три части [splitn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.splitn), где первые две - по разделителю и остаток - уходит в третью, заключительную, которую можно извлечь с помощью [last](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last):

```rust
let input = "some,line,of,text,with,delimiters".to_string();

const PARTS_COUNT: usize = 3;
let rest_substring: &str = input.splitn(PARTS_COUNT, ",").last().expect("...");

println!("{rest_substring}"); // -> "of,text,with,delimiters"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да есть за что зацепиться, спасибо.